# Stata: Gaps between dates

Tags: stata

I have a situation where I need to need to order several dates to see if there is a gap in coverage. My data set looks like this, where `id` is the panel id and `start` and `end` are dates.

```
id start     end
a  01.01.15 02.01.15
a  02.01.15 03.01.15
b  05.01.15 06.01.15
b  07.01.15 08.01.15
b  06.01.15 07.01.15
```

I need to identify any cases where there is a gap in coverage, meaning when the 2nd `start` date for an `id` is greater than the `first` end date for the same id. Also it should be noted that the same `id` can have undetermined number of observations and they might not be in a particular order. I wrote the code below for a case where there are only two observations per `id`.

```
bys id: gen y=1 if end < start[_n+1]
```

However, this code does not produce the desired results. I'm thinking that there should be another way to approach this problem.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want. Do you need to check only first and second observations for each `id`? Or do you mean you need to check succesive observations, ordered in some way? The example data you post doesn't seem very helpful in illustrating the problem either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems sound in essence, assuming that your date variables are really Stata daily date variables formatted suitably. You don't explain at all what "does not produce the desired results" means to you.

The code below creates a sandbox similar to your example, but with string variables converted to daily dates.

Key details include:

Observations must be sorted by date within panel.

The end date for the observation after the last in each panel would always be returned as missing, and so as greater than any known date. The code here returns the corresponding indicator as missing.

```
clear 
input str1 id str8 (s_start s_end) 
a  "01.01.15" "02.01.15"
a  "02.01.15" "03.01.15"
b  "05.01.15" "06.01.15"
b  "07.01.15" "08.01.15"
b  "06.01.15" "07.01.15"
b  "10.01.15" "12.01.15" 
end 

foreach v in start end { 
    gen `v' = daily(s_`v', "DMY", 2050) 
    format `v' %td 
}

// the important line here 
bysort id (start) : gen first = end < start[_n+1] if _n < _N 

list , sepby(id) 

     +----------------------------------------------------------+
     | id    s_start      s_end       start         end   first |
     |----------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |  a   01.01.15   02.01.15   01jan2015   02jan2015       0 |
  2. |  a   02.01.15   03.01.15   02jan2015   03jan2015       . |
     |----------------------------------------------------------|
  3. |  b   05.01.15   06.01.15   05jan2015   06jan2015       0 |
  4. |  b   06.01.15   07.01.15   06jan2015   07jan2015       0 |
  5. |  b   07.01.15   08.01.15   07jan2015   08jan2015       1 |
  6. |  b   10.01.15   12.01.15   10jan2015   12jan2015       . |
     +----------------------------------------------------------+
```